# SQL Aggregate Functions and Group by's

Tags: sql

I am struggling with finding where to start on this question. I feel like I need to find the count of CustomerID for each shipper and group it by district, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated and here are the tables and what I have so far: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCGCG.png)

```
SELECT ShipName,District
FROM Customer, Orders
GROUP BY District, ShipName
```

"How many customers from each district have placed orders handled by each shipper? Your query
should show the shipper company name, the customer district, and the number of customers from
that district for each shipper used. If a shipper has not handled any orders, they should be included in
the list as well. Provide SQL and number of rows."

Comment: You'll want a left join, Look into `count()`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: ^^ I realize it's a work in progress, but your current query demonstrates one of the most compelling reasons to avoid old style joins: (from the link above) *"....What if you forget the join criteria? You've inadvertently turned it into a [CROSS JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) (otherwise known as the Cartesian Product). ..."*  That's exactly what your query is doing.  To put it in perspective, if the two tables contain a mere 1000 records, the result of your query will be **1 million records**!